# Altair how to use nested arguments in a custom theme? (facet headers)

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I'm trying to create a custom theme in Altair where one of the things I'm changing is the font of the headers in a facet chart. I'm not sure if I'm formatting the nested argument wrong, or if it's something different specifically with facet headers.

Here's the code that I would expect to change the facet headers but doesn't:

```
import altair as alt
from altair.expr import datum
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris.url

def custom_theme():
    return {
        'config': {
            'facet' : {
                'header' : {
                    'labelFont' : 'Lato'
                }
            }
        }
    }

alt.themes.register('custom_theme', custom_theme)

alt.themes.enable('custom_theme')

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180
).facet(
    column='species:N'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the information in the reference, the desired font was set by disabling facets. References were referenced [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/configuration.html?highlight=theme#config-header).

```
import altair as alt
from altair.expr import datum
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris.url

def custom_theme():
    return {
        'config': {
            #'facet' : {
                'header' : {
                    'labelFont' : 'Lato',
                    'labelFontSize': 22
              # }
            }
        }
    }

alt.themes.register('custom_theme', custom_theme)

alt.themes.enable('custom_theme')

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180
).facet(
    column='species:N'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Fonts depend on my local environment installation and may be different from what you expect.